# How to stop spam messages on contact form - Silverstripe

Tags: php, recaptcha, silverstripe, spam-prevention, recaptcha-v3

I have a contact form on my website which uses `reCAPTCHA version 2` to help prevent spam messages. However, quite a few get passed through! How could I stop these? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the contents of ContactForm.php file:

```
class ContactForm extends Form {

    public function __construct(Controller $controller, $name)
    {
        $emails = array(
            'e-mail address here'=>'General',
            'e-mail address here'=>'Sales',
            'e-mail address here'=>'Technical Support',
        );

        $fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Name')->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Name'),
            EmailField::create('Email')->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Email'),
            DropdownField::create('Destination', 'Enquiry', $emails)->setEmptyString("(Department)"),
            TextareaField::create('Message')
                ->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Message')
                ->setAttribute('rows', 9)
                ->setAttribute('cols', 25),
            LiteralField::create('Captcha', '<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY KEY GOES HERE"></div>')
        );

        $actions = new FieldList(
            FormAction::create('Contact', 'Send')->setAttribute('disabled',true)
        );

        $validator = new RequiredFields('Name', 'Email', 'Message', 'Destination');
        //return Form::create($controller, $name, $fields, $actions, $validator);
        parent::__construct($controller, $name, $fields, $actions, $validator);
    }

    public function Contact($data)
    {
        $email = new Email();
        $email->setFrom($data['Email']);
        $email->setSubject("Website Enquiry");
        $email->setTo($data['Destination']);
        $messageBody = "<p><strong>Name:</strong> {$data['Name']}</p><p><strong>Message:</strong> {$data['Subject']}</p><p><strong>Message:</strong> {$data['Message']}</p>";
        $email->setBody($messageBody);
        $email->send();

        Controller::curr()->redirectBack();
    }

}
```

This is the code ContactPage_Controller.php file:

```
<?php

class ContactPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    public static $allowed_actions = array(
        'ContactForm'
    );

    public function ContactForm(){
        return ContactForm::create($this, 'ContactForm');
    }
}
```

This is the contents of ContactPage.ss file:

```
<div class="service-menu-wrapper">
    <ul class="services-menu">
        <% control $ServiceMenu %>
            <li><a class="hvr-float-shadow internal-link $LinkingMode" href="$Link"><i class="fa $Icon"></i></a></li>
        <% end_control %>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="typography container">
    <div class="content-container js-content">

        <article>
            <div class="custom-title">
                <span>Contact us</span>
            </div>

            <div class="panel">
                <div class="section left contact-form-wrapper">
                    $ContactForm
                </div>
                <div class="section right map">

                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d92480.79610056261!2d-4.0153309783259425!3d52.475305088108385!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xc657c04368dfd9ad!2sAtebol!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1526831824458"
                            width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
                            allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $("form").submit(function(event) {

        var recaptcha = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
        if (recaptcha === "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Please fill in ReCaptcha");
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is the content of ContactPage.php file:

```
<?php

class ContactPage extends Page
{

    private static $db = array();

    private static $has_one = array();

    private static $has_many = array();

    private static $summary_fields = array();

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that validates the reCAPTCHA. The way this code looks to me, all you do is add the reCAPTCHA form field. You have to actually block messages that failed the reCAPTCHA test.

Comment: oh, I see you are setting disabled on the button and I guess reCAPTCHA will remove the disabled tag from the input later. But that's just client side. Nothing stopps a user from opening dev-tools and removing disabled manually. Or a spambot just ignoring that.

Comment: Hi @Zauberfisch. Thanks for your help. Regarding your first message, I'm actually working off an existing website so I'm not exactly sure what they have implemented. Do you know where I could find the code if reCAPTCHA messages are checked? Also, you have a good point about the Submit button being disabled... do you know how I could change this so that spambots (or someone) can't bypass this? Many thanks

Comment: Well, you need to validate that the reCAPTCHA was filled out correctly on the server side (php). So in your case, inside the function "Contact", or even better would be a custom FormField Class with a validate method which is thenn called by RequiredFields. But first please update your question with more details: Is this the full ContactPage.php file? Can you include any template files that are related please?

Comment: Thanks @Zauberfisch. Yes you're right, it seems the 'validation' code isn't included? I'm not an expert with PHP code so I don't really know what would need to be included? Could you advise on what code I would need or where to check if the code already exists somewhere? I'll update my question now to include as much detail/code I have!

Comment: Consider hiring a programming expert then. You expect us to do your job for you? SO is not a hiring service. We help people solve problems, but that doesn’t mean we do their job entirely. You should refer to the framework’s documentation how to validate user input correctly.

Comment: This is the only part of the website that needs addressing. I was hoping with a little help from you guys you could guide me to a possible solution. My PHP knowledge is quite expansive but 'rusty' I would say!